# Empty $_POST. Values end up in $GLOBAL instead

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have been struggling with a strange $_POST problem since i reinstalled my OS. I have decided to return working on one of my free time projects and I have noticed that all of my POST requests are not working, but I'm sure they have worked before.

What i noticed is that all the $_POST values always end up in $GLOBALS instead and $_POST array is always empty. Any ideas?

Using PHP Version 5.6.19

**php.ini**:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/42704655/php.ini

**Script:**

```
    $('#login-form').on('submit', function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php/login.php",
        data: $("#login-form").serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
    });

    return false;
});
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/login.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js" async></script>
    <script src="scripts/login-script.js" async></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="login">
        <form method="post" id="login-form" action="php/login.php">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Login:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="login" form="login-form" class="input" autofocus></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Password:</td>
                    <td><input type="password" name="password" form="login-form" class="input"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <button type="submit" form="login-form">Login</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" id="input-td">
                        <p id="errorMsgs"></p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
```

**$GLOBALS** ('test1' as login, 'test2' as pw)

```
array(8) { ["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"]=> string(26) "login=test1&password=test2" ["_GET"]=> array(0) { } ["_POST"]=> array(0) { } ["_COOKIE"]=> array(0) { } ["_FILES"]=> array(0) { } ["GLOBALS"]=> *RECURSION* ["login"]=> string(0) "" ["pass"]=> string(0) "" }
```

Comment: What's your OS? What method did you use to install php after you refreshed your OS?

Comment: Win10 (same as before). Installed XAMPP and just copied over php (and of course fixed all the ext paths after that)

Comment: Did you copy your php.ini from an earlier php version? I see register_globals is still referenced - it should be removed completely in 5.6. Also I see you have it set to not populate HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA, but you're still able to access it that way. Either something is messed up in your ini or something got messed up on install.

Comment: No i didn't copy it from any earlier version. I guess i'll try to install php using some other method or so. Any recommendations?

Comment: I have uploaded the script to my web server and it works totally fine there. I have also just got myself php 7 but the problem persists.

Comment: since the answer doesn't help you. I am deleting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i have just figured it out. It's my webserver build in into the IDE that has some bugs. https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206999125-PhPStorm-10-does-not-allow-POST-method